# Linux - "Too many open files" with pipe, how to debug

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, pipe

I have a Java program which will throw 'Too many open files' error after running for about 3 minutes. Increasing the open file limit doesn't work, because it still uses up all the limit, just slower. So there is something wrong with my program and I need to find out.

Here is what I did, `10970` is the pid

- Check opened files of the Java process using `cat /proc/10970/fd` and find out most of them are pipes
- Use `lsof -p 10970 | grep FIFO` to list all pipes and find about 450 pipes
- Pipes look like below

> java    10970 service    1w  FIFO                0,8      0t0    5890 pipe
>
> java    10970 service    2w  FIFO                0,8      0t0    5890 pipe
>
> java    10970 service  169r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 2450696 pipe
>
> java    10970 service  201r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 2450708 pipe

But I don't know how to continue. `0,8` in the output above means device numbers. How can I find devices with these numbers?

**Update**

The program is a TCP server and receiving socket connections from client and processing messages. I have two environments. In Production environment it works fine, but in Test environment it has this issue recently. In Production environment I don't see so many pipes. The code and infrastructure of these two environments are same, both managed by Chef.

Comment: This question is vague. What does your program do? Also, do you close your "connection" by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how to continue.

What you need to do is to identify the place or places in your Java code where you are opening these pipes ... and make sure that they are always closed when you are done with them.

The best way to ensure that the pipes are closed is to explicitly close them when you are done with them.  For example (using input streams instead of sockets ...):

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("somefile.txt");
    try {
         // Use file
    } finally {
         is.close();
    }
```

In Java 7 or later, you can write that more succinctly as ///

```
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("somefile.txt")) {
         // Use file
    }
```

In the latter, the `InputStream object` is automatically closed when the `try` completes ... in an implicit `finally` block.

---

> 0,8 in the output above means device numbers. How can I find devices with these numbers?

That is probably irrelevant to solving the problem.  Focus on why the file descriptors are not being closed.  The knowing what device numbers mean doesn't help.

> In Production environment I don't see so many pipes.

That's probably a red-herring too.  It could be caused by the GC running more frequently, and closing the orphaned file descriptors before the become a problem.

(But forcing the GC to run is not a solution.  You should not rely on the GC to close file descriptors.  It is inefficient and unreliable.)

Comment: How do I know which java methods create linux pipes?